# How to manage multiple labels

Tags: c#, label

I'm trying to make a little typing game using forms and need some help with labels. So, I need to create several labels with different text, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do it with `Label word = new Label()` so that I could get control of any or at least first created Label at any time later?

Maybe there's some kind of  specific topic which I should read more about?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of labels and access them later by index

```
Label []words = new Label[10];
```

If you do not know at compile time that how many labels you would need then you can use [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

```
List<Label> lstLabels = new List<Label>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed limit of labels then you can do what Adil had mentioned above and can access them later.Like,

```
 Label []words = new Label[10];
```

However if you have dynamic number of labels than one option is to add them at run time to the form and later access them using Reflection.

```
  foreach(Control c in yourForm.Controls)
  if(c is label)
  {
      //your code
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your labels as:

```
Label l = new Label();
l.Location = somepoint;
l.Text = "text" + this.Controls.Count;
this.Controls.Add(l);
```

After to retrieve all labels(in this example it will be under a button click event):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //assuming there might be other controls,
        //it will get all labels in the form
        Label[] c = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();

        //...do what you need
    }
```

The labels are in the same order as added.

If you want to get just 1 label based on,for example,text of label entered on textbox(since you said there all different text):

```
Label c1 = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(l => l.Text.ToLower() == textBox1.Text.ToLower()).Single();
```